# Group and Match aggregrate MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a documents like this:

```
{
u '_id': ObjectId('5534cd32e4b0d5f14e6aa27d'),
u 'geoip': {
  u 'coordinates': [-96.8353,
      32.9299
    ],
    u 'region_name': u 'TX',
    u 'latitude': 32.9299,
    u 'ip': u '173.193.154.240',
    u 'area_code': 972,
    u 'continent_code': u 'NA',
    u 'country_code3': u 'USA',
    u 'country_code2': u 'US',
    u 'city_name': u 'Dallas',
    u 'longitude': -96.8353,
    u 'timezone': u 'America/Chicago',
    u 'country_name': u 'UnitedStates',
    u 'postal_code': u '75244',
    u 'real_region_name': u 'Texas',
    u 'dma_code': 623,
    u 'location': [-96.8353,
      32.9299
    ]
},
u 'dest_ip': u '173.193.154.240'
}
```

What I want to achieve is... `group by country name`

Desired output:

```
{
  'country_name': 'US',
  'count': 110,
  'location': [10, 10]
}
```

What I am doing now is:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {"country_name": "$geoip.country_name"},
            "count": {"$sum": 1},
            },

    }
])
```

This works, but doesn't give me the location. If I want location I would do:

```
"_id": {"country_name": "$geoip.country_name", "location": "$geoip.location"}
```

But the problem here is we have lot of locations `(different latitude and longitude) in the same country_name.`

So, what I want is just `one latitude and longitude with the country name.`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want *one* pair of latitude longitude, you might use the [`$first` accumulator operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {"country_name": "$geoip.country_name"},
            "count": {"$sum": 1},
            "longitude": {"$first": "$longitude"},              
            "latitude": {"$first": "$latitude"}
            }
    }
])
```

Using `$first` will guarantee that both longitude and latitude are coming from the *same* document. There is a [`$last` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) too, but there is not much benefit in using it here, I think.

Finally, to quote the documentation: *"when using $first[resp: $last] in a $group stage, the $group stage should follow a $sort stage to have the input documents in a defined order."* But according to your description, that was not needed here.